# How to capitalize only first letter of a sentence

Tags: powerquery, m

I know of the m function [Text.Proper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-proper) which capitalizes all words in a sentence. However, I want to know how I can capitalize only the first word of a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of decent answers already, but here's another option that demonstrates a couple more functions:

```
Text.Upper(Text.At([Text],0)) & Text.Range([Text], 1, Text.Length([Text]) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of the following.  You didn't specify any details

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Converted", each Text.Upper(Text.Middle([Column1],0,1))&Text.Middle([Column1],1,Text.Length([Column1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Excel style ;-)

```
let
    Input = "text to capitalize",
    Output = Text.Upper(Text.Start(Input,1)) & Text.End(Input,Text.Length(Input)-1)
in
    Output
```